# Twitter Bootstrap: Button is always large

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My Twitter Bootstrap "logout" button is not styling appropriately.

Here is the small snippet of the button:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-small" href="logout.php" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Return to sign-in">Logout</a>
```

And here is the entirety of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Cornerstone</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <!-- Le styles -->
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way
                 to the bottom of the topbar */
            }
            h1 {
                color: #624949;
            }
            h2 {
                color: #624949;
            }
            p {
                color: #624949;
            }
            .btn-custom-lighten.active {
                color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
            }
            .btn-custom-lighten {
                color: #ffffff;
                text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
                background-color: #644a4a;
                background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #584141, #755757);
                background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#584141), to(#755757));
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #584141, #755757);
                background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #584141, #755757);
                background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #584141, #755757);
                background-repeat: repeat-x;
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff584141', endColorstr='#ff755757', GradientType=0);
                border-color: #755757 #755757 #493636;
                border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
                *background-color: #755757;
                /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */

                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
            }
            .btn-custom-lighten:hover, .btn-custom-lighten:focus, .btn-custom-lighten:active, .btn-custom-lighten.active, .btn-custom-lighten.disabled, .btn-custom-lighten[disabled] {
                color: #ffffff;
                background-color: #755757;
                *background-color: #674c4c;
            }
            .btn-custom-lighten:active, .btn-custom-lighten.active {
                background-color: #584141;
            }

            form {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cstonecc.org/favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body background="assets/img/background.jpg">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Jumbotron -->
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1 class="">Dashboard</h1>
                <p class="lead">
                    Welcome to the dashboard. Configure below!
                </p>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-small" href="logout.php" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Return to sign-in">Logout</a>
            </div>

            <br />

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span4">
                    <button class="btn btn-large btn-custom-lighten" type="button"
                    data-toggle="modal" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click to configure" data-target="#carouselModal">
                        Carousel
                    </button>
                    <div id="carouselModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                &times;
                            </button>
                            <h3>Carousel</h3>
                        </div>
                        <form action="update-carousel.php" method="post">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <section class="row">
                                    <div>
                                        <p>
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                                            <textarea name="carousel" rows="4" style="margin: 0px 0px 10px; width: 501px; height: 101px; max-width: 501px;"><?php $file = new SPLFileObject('carousel.txt');
                                            foreach ($file as $line)
                                                echo($line);
                    ?></textarea>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </section>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                    Close
                                </button>
                                <input type="submit" id="carousel-save" name="carousel-save" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" />

                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <p></p>
                </div></form>
                <div class="span4">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <p>
                <br />
            </p>
            <p>
                <br />
            </p>
            <p>
                <br />
            </p>
            <p>
                <br />
            </p>
            <!--<hr>-->

            <div class="footer">
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <p class="">
                    Copyright 2013 (C) <a style="color: #000000;" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visit our website" href="http://cstonecc.org">Cornerstone</a>
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /container -->

        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 20px;
                padding-bottom: 60px;
            }

            /* Custom container */
            .container {
                margin: 0 auto;
                max-width: 1000px;
            }
            .container > hr {
                margin: 60px 0;
            }

            /* Main marketing message */
            .jumbotron {
                margin: 80px 0;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .jumbotron h1 {
                font-size: 100px;
                line-height: 1;
            }
            .jumbotron .lead {
                font-size: 24px;
                line-height: 1.25;
            }
            .jumbotron .btn {
                font-size: 21px;
                padding: 14px 24px;
            }

            /* Supporting marketing content */
            .marketing {
                margin: 60px 0;
            }
            .marketing p + h4 {
                margin-top: 28px;
            }

            /* Customize the navbar links to be fill the entire space of the .navbar */
            .navbar .navbar-inner {
                padding: 0;
            }
            .navbar .nav {
                margin: 0;
                display: table;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .navbar .nav li {
                display: table-cell;
                width: 1%;
                float: none;
            }
            .navbar .nav li a {
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: center;
                border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
                border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
            }
            .navbar .nav li:first-child a {
                border-left: 0;
                border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
            }
            .navbar .nav li:last-child a {
                border-right: 0;
                border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
            }

        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should never place `style` tags outside of a HTML document's `head` as this will force the page to render more times than it needs to.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! As for my question, I figured it out myself. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this problem by removing the formatting of .btn within Jumbotron.

In other terms, remove this from your styling:

```
.jumbotron .btn {
                font-size: 21px;
                padding: 14px 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look all the buttons HTML and looks on the URL. It may help you:

http://twitterbootstrap.org/category/documentation/bootstrap-css

There all the button and HTML explained well and the difference between Twitter Bootstrap 3.0.0 & 2.3.2

thanks